# Slow startup in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In the last month (may be it started happening before but we didn't realize) we have experienced a very slow startup in Xamarin apps, it takes about 7 seconds.
Since this wasn't happening, may be some Xamarin update that we installed is causing this behavior, but we don't know.

This is a very important issue for us. Can you help us to detect the cause of the problem? Is this related to some change in Xamarin?

Comment: To isolate the update issue, I *think* you can downgrade Xamarin Studio. Going back to a previous version and rebuilding would maybe help you isolate the issue.

Maybe try creating sample version of your app to see if it's slow  to start too. It's more likely that you've added something that delays your startup in a recent push. But I'm guessing you've already tried compiling with a 30 day old commit and didn't get any result so... I'd try the same process with a downgraded version of XS.

Comment: It seems that the time is being consumed loading libraries and some other initialization stuff. This project uses several libraries, in some devices the libraries are loaded faster, and in others slower. 7 seconds for initialization is a horrible performance for a mobile app.

Comment: Different devices can have different performances die to differing CPUs, etc. There will always be some performance differences on differing devices, and the same is true on desktop apps. But as suggested, see if there is a difference between on older version of Xamarin Android and the current stable version. If you note a significant difference in start up time between two versions of Xamarin Android with your same exact code base deploying to the same device, then I would suggest you file a bug at:
bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug
noting the older XA version that led to faster start up.

Comment: Also, are you noticing this for a Release build or just a debug build? Release builds should tend to be faster on start up. And here is a link to our guide on improving performance for X.Android: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/performance/

Answer (score 0):

There could be number of reasons for slow build time, you can enable [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) identify the longest running build tasks